# Retrieve data in callback function

Tags: node.js, callback, duckdb

I am new TO JS and using duckdb with NodeJS, I receive responses in the callback function and able to console.log out the data

The result

```
db.all('SELECT sku, sum(sales) as sales from B group by all', function(err, responses) {
    const newData = []
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    else{
    for(let row of responses) {
        newData.push(row)
        console.log(row)
      }
}

});
```

```
{ sku: 'C', sales: 30 }
{ sku: 'A', sales: 35 }
{ sku: 'B', sales: 20 }
```

The next line of code I try to

```
console.log(newData)
```

but the it failed the said

```
ReferenceError: newData is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactor the code it still does not work as expected

```
// Declare newData outside the callback function
const newData = [];

db.all('SELECT sku, sum(sales) as sales from B group by all', function(err, responses) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    for (let row of responses) {
      newData.push(row); // Append the data to newData
      console.log(row);
    }
  }
});

console.log("newData", newData); // Now newData can be accessed here
```

It shows

```
newData []
{ sku: 'C', sales: 30 }
{ sku: 'A', sales: 35 }
{ sku: 'B', sales: 20 }
```

I believe it console.log the newData before the newData push new object to it.

Answer (score -2):

The problem you are having is due to the **scope** of the newData variable. Currently, the newData variable is declared **inside** the callback function, which means it can only be accessed within this code block.

To solve this problem, you can declare the newData variable **outside** of the callback function, so that it is accessible throughout the body of your code. Here's how you can do it:

```
// Declare newData outside the callback function
const newData = [];

db.all('SELECT sku, sum(sales) as sales from B group by all', function(err, responses) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    for (let row of responses) {
      newData.push(row); // Append the data to newData
      console.log(row);
    }
  }
});

console.log(newData); // Now newData can be accessed here
```

With this change, the newData variable will be accessible outside the callback function, and you can use it to display the data or perform other operations after the query.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since your two answers today appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.